# How to limit number of "Promoted to Front Page" option for each user/role

Tags: 7

I want to limit the option "Promoted to Front Page" per role.
For example, a user with role "promoter" should only be able to promote 5 nodes a day to promote to front page.
And same with sticky option.

I am using 'rules_link' module as well.

Any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve above by writing a small custom module in Drupal... Steps are outlined below to achieve the same.

- Create install file and define schema hook with table name as user_promote_counter with below fields
- uid, timestamp, nid
- Using [hook_node_presave($node)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) update above table with a record of uid, timestamp, nid of the node updated whenever promote is set to true so that you can track only promoted to front page actions.
- Use [hook_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) in your custom module to verify current user who has promoter role exceeded the limit of 5 by querying above table using timestamp and uid columns. Raise an error if limit is exceeded. That will prevent user to promote more than 5 nodes per day.

Comment: You rocks man. I am almost there now. :)

Comment: I will be putting all the code when I am done, to help others if they are in the same requirement.

Comment: in hook_node_presave, I can compare the filed value if it was going to be checked or not by using...if ($node->promote == 1 && $node->original->promote == 0){}, but cant do it in hook_node_presave. Any help?

Comment: More explanation, I want to validate if a checkbox is going to be newly CHECKED or it was already CHECKED.

Comment: You can run a query to get old value on node table by nid as a condition... For Example: Forum module does this to get old tid from database here http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21modules%21forum%21forum.module/function/forum_node_presave/7

Comment: Not working for me. InfactI dont understand that thing. Looking for somthing similar to if ($node->promote == 1 && $node->original->promote == 0){} or how should through error in hook_node_presave